# d3.js (dúvida sobre gráfico de barras)

Tags: d3.js

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gráfico de Barras</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var dataArray = [30, 15, 50];
        var canvas = d3.select("body")
                        .append("svg")
                        .attr("width", 500)
                        .attr("height", 500);
        var bars = canvas.selectAll("rect")
                          .data(dataArray)
                          .enter()
                            .append("rect")
                            .attr("width", function(d) {return d*10;})
                            .attr("height", 50)
                            .attr("y", function(d, i){return i*100});
        console.log(bars);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Ocorre que se alterarmos a linha `.attr("width", function(d) {return d*10;})` para `.attr("width", 30, 15, 50)` creio q deveríamos obter o mesmo "**Gráfico Correto**" acima, porém menor, proporcionalmente, e isso não se verifica, conforme o "**Gráfico supostamente errado**", com imagem logo adiante.

Gostaria de saber porque o "**Gráfico supostamente errado**" não é uma miniatura proporcional do "**Gráfico Correto**".

**Gráfico Aparentemente Errado**
[[image: Imagem mostrando o Gráfico Aparentemente Errado]
<sup>clique para visualizar no tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VOqO8.png)

**Gráfico Certo**
[[image: Imagem mostrando o Gráfico Certo]
<sup>clique para visualizar no tamanho original</sup>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ugJf.png)

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Perdão, mas acredito que a pergunta está clara.